# Bound constraints ignored Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, bounds, portfolio

I have the following code working out the efficient frontier for a portfolio of assets:

```
lb=Bounds(:,1);
ub=Bounds(:,2);

P = Portfolio('AssetList', AssetList,'LowerBound', lb, 'UpperBound', ub, 'Budget', 1);
P = P.estimateAssetMoments(AssetReturns)
[Passetmean, Passetcovar] = P.getAssetMoments

pwgt = P.estimateFrontier(20);
[prsk, pret] = P.estimatePortMoments(pwgt);
```

It works fine apart from the fact that it ignores the constraints to some extent (results below). How do I set the constraints to be hard constraints- i.e. prevent it from ignoring an upper bound of zero? For example, when I set an upper and lower bound to zero (i.e. I do not want a particular asset to be included in a portfolio) I still get values in the calculated portfolio weights for that asset, albeit very small ones, coming out as part of the optimised portfolio.
Lower bounds (lb), upper bounds (ub), and one of the portfolio weights (pwgt) are set out below:

```
lb                  ub                     pwgt(:,1)
0                   0                   1.06685493772574e-16
0                   0                   4.17200995972422e-16
0                   0                   0
0                   0                   2.76688394418301e-16
0                   0                   3.39138439553466e-16
0.192222222222222   0.252222222222222   0.192222222222222
0.0811111111111111  0.141111111111111   0.105624956477606
0.0912121212121212  0.151212121212121   0.0912121212121212
0.0912121212121212  0.151212121212121   0.0912121212121212
0.0306060606060606  0.0906060606060606  0.0306060606060606
0.0306060606060606  0.0906060606060606  0.0306060606060606
0.121515151515152   0.181515151515152   0.181515151515152
0.0508080808080808  0.110808080808081   0.110808080808081
0.00367003367003366 0.0636700336700337  0.0388531580005063
0.00367003367003366 0.0636700336700337  0.0636700336700338
0.00367003367003366 0.0636700336700337  0.0636700336700337
0                   0                   0
0                   0                   0
0                   0                   1.29236898960272e-16
```

I could use something like: `pwgt=floor(pwgt*1000)/1000;`, but is there not a more elegant solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that your bound has not been ignored.

You are calculating with floating point numbers, and hence `0` and `4.17200995972422e-16` are both close enough to 0 to let your program allow them.

My recommendation would indeed be to round your results (or simply display less decimals with `format short`), however I would do the rounding like this:

```
pwgt=round(pwgt*100000)/100000;
```

Note that the other results may also be 'above' the upper bound, however this will not become visible due to the insignificance.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues like this with a laminate/engineering properties code, which was propogating errors all over everything. I fixed it by taking all of the values I had, and systematically converting them from double to sym, and suddenly my 1e-16 values became real zeros, that I could also `eval(val)` and still see as zeros! This may help, but you may have to go inside of the .m files you're running, and have the numbers convert to sym with `val = sym(val)`.

I can't remember for certain, but I think Matlab functions MIGHT change sym to double once they receive the data for their own internal processing.